# button switch properties constraint

Tags: python, panel

I want to do switching between FK / IK using the button, not a slider, and do this in the form of a 2 button ( fk and ik)

Pressed fk button - value 1 in the constrain copytransform fk (copytransform ik = 0)

Press ik button - constrain copytransform ik = 1 copytransform fk = 0
without driver

Here is the standard panel code:

```
import bpy
class RigUIPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My RigUI"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D' 
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS' 
    bl_category = "RigUI"

    def draw(self, context): 
        layout = self.layout 
        obj = context.object
        row = layout.row() 
        row.label(text="FK/IK Switch") 

        row = layout.row() 
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")
        row = layout.row() 
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")          #here is a button for example, but it            now performs the function of adding a cube#

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RigUIPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RigUIPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

One method for doing this is to create a scene bool prop 1 for each custom prop, this could then use an update 1 or get/set 1 call that would allow it to update the custom prop for `false = 0` `true = 1` but I do not understand how to do it